# How to diable Android Studio from forcing to install older version of SDK?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I recently try to open Eclipse project to Android Studio that used targetSdk 16.
But I forgot to change the target Sdk before importing to Android Studio. I have latest version of Android Sdk(19-22) so I dont want to install SDK 16.

But Android Studio is showing following error every time I try to build:

```
Error:failed to find target android-16 : D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk
```

**Install missing platform(s) and sync project**

How can I fix it and stop Android Studio from forcing me to install older version of SDK?

Comment: Change `minSdkVersion` in your build.gradle file might help.

Comment: Edit the manifest file of eclipse project and after that import the project in Android studio.

Comment: @PrerakSola  hav already imported it before editing manifest file. Now even if I edit manifest file or delete whole project from harddrive imported directory, IDE build stuck saying Install missing platforms.

Comment: Install missing platforms through SDK. After that import the project successfully. Edit the `build.gradle` with the required version of SDK. Rebuild the project again. Once it is successfully built, remove the older SDKs via SDK manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step #1: Close Android Studio.

Step #2: Using a text editor, edit your `build.gradle` files to be what you want in terms of `compileSdkVersion`, `minSdkVersion`, `targetSdkVersion`, etc.

Step #3: Open Android Studio and attempt to use your project.

If you still encounter related problems, then:

Step #4: Close the project from within Android Studio (File > Close Project). This should leave you at the so-called "welcome dialog", listing past projects and options for starting or importing new projects.

Step #5: Using your favorite file-management tool, go into your project directory and delete the `.gradle/` and `.idea/` directories and the file ending in `.iml`.

Step #6: Using your favorite file-management tool, go into your `app/` module directory and delete the file ending in `.iml`.

Step #7: Back in the "welcome dialog", choose "Import project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.)", browse to your project's root directory, and import it.